# Should we include tutorials / articles on the site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Till date, none of the sites on Stack, that I know of, have tutorials or articles posted. What I also observed was that a lot of the professional developers / testers provide links to their blogs on their profiles.

I believe that if all that information was posted on SQA, or any other Stack site, it would provide much more benefit to the users and the reason why I suggest are here:

*It will save time*.

Admit it, no matter how much we ask the users to search and read before posting the questions, we always find a barrage of similar questions that have already been answered.

If we could create an article / tutorial on, say problems with JUnit that beginners commonly encounter, then this could be the first thing that shows up when someone types the title of the question.

Although chances exist that the person will go ahead and post the question, I would say more chances exist that the person will read first. And if that turns out to be a genuine question that has been missed in the *umbrella* article, it can be added there by the moderator / expert / veteran.

*Provide a better platform for learning*

I don't deny that a lot of sites **do exist** that provide some really nice tutorials on various computer topics. What they do lack is what problems are commonly encountered by beginners. A **lot** of questions are closed not because they fall out of scope but because the questioner does not know how to frame the questions properly.

If we could eliminate the root cause, *confusion*, by providing better quality learning material then we will automatically have higher quality questions.

We can have the tutorials / articles differentiated on the basis of audience rather than complexity. What happens a lot of time is that beginners (like me) go on to read expert stuff, get confused and then post sub-par questions (like me).

*Provide nifty tips and tricks*

Now this is useful only for the pros who spend most of their times testing and finding mistakes in the programs of the mere mortals. Nothing is better than finding a quick way to do a thing that someone has tried and tested.

---

Bottom line, the mods here do spend copious amount of time answering questions. If repetition could be avoided, then more information could be dispensed to the members here.
Just my humble suggestion. Wanna hear back from the mods.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of work has gone into the stack-exchange format to make a successful site. I think one of the main reasons that this format does not work so well for testing is that our answers are typically more "shades of grey" than black or white.

I would recommend that if you want to provide this sort of content you should simply seed the site with both question and a pre-written answer in community wiki, as this is a completely sanctioned and encouraged way of putting content onto these sites.

Comment: Exactly. But if all the wiki answers were organised into a section which the users could quickly refer to, then that would be awesome.

Comment: Isn't that what tags are for ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: I was thinking of `Articles` section, beside the `Questions` :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the idea in general is good, assuming users will put effort to use these articles before asking a question.

Given that, no additional feature must be implemented in the engine to support that. SO does this by describing tags in an exhaustive way in an info section. For instance, [`java`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) tag lists: Beginners' resources, Day to day resources, Advanced resources, etc.

The only problems with that feature I see:

- It is not exposed well and it might be harder to find for newcomers.
- Who is privileged to add info to tags?

Comment: Only the experienced people. Like Mr. Bruce McLeod (with a diamond beside his name). Now as for the first point, only the mods can come up with a creative solution for it.

Comment: You must have min 4000 of reputation. But below that level you still may send tag edits for review, the same way as you may propose changes to the question or answer. See http://sqa.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user